# hog training for object detection from images and videos

Tags: python, opencv

I have saved positive images in pos folder and negative images in neg folder.I am using HOGDescriptor for feature extraction.But it creates a new dataset for each image.I don't know about creating a single file from multiple images.Someone please tell me how can I and create hog descriptor from multiple images and use them for object detection

Also explain cv2.HOGDescriptor
().setSVMDetector()

Comment: you must generate a hog descriptor for each image and then use machine learning like svm to create a function that decides whether one hog descriptor is the object or  not.